# Conditional Average with a function

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to average a range but only if one condition is true.

```
   A B C
1: A 1 2
2: B 3 4
3: C 5 6
4: D 7 8
5: A 1 6
6: E 8 9
7: E 5 8
```

What I want is if the char I'm looking for is "A" then I want my average to produce something to the form of:

```
(1/2 + 1/6) /2
=AVERAGEIF(A:A, "="&SomeOtherVariable, B:B/C:C)
```

I want to avoid creating an extra column because the sheet that this data is on is taken from a google form and I am not sure how the form will take having a new column added to it.

Comment: What about using a second sheet to calculate the conditional average for the unique elements of column A instead of for each row, as the last will return redundant values?

Comment: I just investigated and I can add a new column and that will not screw up new form data, but when new entries are added they wont have the correct function in that row. I think I should ask that question in another new question though.

Comment: Actually there are several questions in [webapps.se] about how to deal with form responses and calculations made on them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Short answer

Instead of AVERAGEIF use an array formula as AVERAGEIF requires a range as it's third parameter.

## Explanation

The below formula could be used to calculate the average for each category without having to use an auxiliary column and as it use open ended references, it will not require to be modified when new form responses be submitted.

```
=ArrayFormula(
  QUERY(
    FILTER(
      {'Sheet1'!A:A,'Sheet1'!B:B/'Sheet1!C:C},LEN('Sheet1'!A:A)
    ),
    "select Col1,AVG(Col2) group by Col1")
 )
```

Using the example source data provided by the OP, the result is the following:

```
+---+---+--------------+
|   | A |      B       |
+---+---+--------------+
| 1 |   | avg          |
| 2 | A | 0.3333333333 |
| 3 | B | 0.75         |
| 4 | C | 0.8333333333 |
| 5 | D | 0.875        |
| 6 | E | 0.7569444444 |
+---+---+--------------+
```

- `{'Sheet1'!A:A,'Sheet1'!B:B/'Sheet1!C:C}` creates an array with two columns, the first one is the category column, the second calculates the dividend of Column B divided by Column C.
- The FILTER function is used to remove blank rows.
- The QUERY function is used to calculate the average for each category in the first column.

## References

- [Using arrays in Google Sheets](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276?hl=en)
- [FILTER](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=en)
- [QUERY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en)

Comment: That does exactly what I wanted it to, thanks. I haven't really used QUERY much, and i didn't even know you could build more than 1 column tables with ARRAYFORMULA.

Answer (score 1):

NOTE: The following was valid for the [revision 2](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/revisions/91209/2)

The error occurs because the comparison operator should be concatenated with `SomeOtherVariable` by using the ampersand `&` operator or CONCAT or CONCATENATE functions.

By the other hand, the third parameter of AVERAGEIF, when used, should be a range, it can't be an array.

Add a column to do the division, `B:B/C:C`, let say  it's Column D, then the final formula will be

```
=AVERAGEIF(A:A, "="&SomeOtherVariable,D:D)
```

Comment: I edited to show the changes you suggested but I want to avoid an extra column because the sheet is generated off of a google form. meaning either the form won't know where to put the new entries. or every so often I would need to copy the formula into the new entries. What is the difference between a range and an array?